# Prove that any integer $n$ whose prime factorization is $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$ is a perfect $m$th power iff $a_i$ is a multiple of $m$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I am a high school student self-studying number theory and came across this question in the book *Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics*:

Prove that any integer $n$ whose prime factorization is $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$ is a perfect square iff $2|a_i$, and in general $n$ is an $m^{th}$ power iff all $a_i$ is a multiple of $m$.

I managed to prove this for $m=2$, as the question said, but am unable to even get started on the second part, because my proof required an assumption which I do not know if holds for the general case also.

Please check the proof below:

$n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$ where $n$ is a perfect square.

Let us assume, if possble, that there exist some powers $a_i\geq 0$ such that $a_i=2b_i+1$.

We know that the number of factors $\tau(n)=(a_1+1)(a_2+1)...(a_k+1)$. We can write each $a_i$ as $a_i= 2b_i$ or $a_i=2b_i+1$.

Now $\tau(n)=(2b_1+1)(2b_2+1)...(2b_i+1+1)...(2b_k+1)$.

$\Rightarrow 2|\tau (n)$

$\color{red}{\textrm{However we know that every perfect square has an odd number of factors.}}$ This contradicts our assumption that $n$ is a perfect square.

Thus, our assumption is wrong and no such $a_i=2b_i+1$ exists.

QED.

Can the assumption highlighted in red be generalized for any number which is an $m^{th}$ power? And if not, is there a better way of doing it than my proof?

Comment: That is very roundabout. How about simply: "Suppose $n=b^m$ for some $b$. Then $b$ has a prime factorization ... (bla bla) ... and therefore $n$ has the following prime factorization ... (bla bla) ... and since prime factorizations are unique ..."

Comment: I tried it that way, but that leads me to the statement $n=(q_1q_2...q_k)^mp_i^{a_i}$ where $m$ does not divide $a_i$. Can I just dismiss this as not being an $m^{th}$ power? I assumed that there was no way to say that.

Comment: How on earth do you get that statement? What is the prime factorization you assume for $b$? Why are you treating a particular $p_i$ specially?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. Can you elaborate on that statement 'by the uniqueness of prime factorisation...'?

Comment: If you have computed _one_ prime factorization of $b^m$ where all of the exponents are multiples of $m$, then you know that this is _the_ prime factorization of $n$ (because prime factorizations are unique), and therefore the $\alpha_i$s must be the numbers you have just concluded are multiples of $m$.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you.